# Dynamic / Generic Inheritance in Python

Tags: python, generics, inheritance, dynamic

I am trying to achieve the following: I need a class that represents a variable of a specific type, but this type can vary. As an example:

```
var1 = Variable(int)
var2 = Variable(bool)
var3 = Variable(str)
```

Then I can change the value of the variable with `param1.value = 10` or `param1.set_value(10)`. Moreover, instances of Variable should behave as they were their base types. E.g. `print(a)` should print 10 and `isinstance(var1, int)` should return true as well.

Any idea how to achieve this?

If I only needed one type it would be easy:

```
class Variable(int):
    def __new__(cls, value):
        return super(Variable, cls).__new__(cls, value)

var1 = Variable(10)
print(var1)                   # 10
print(isinstance(var1, int))  # True
```

But I don't have any success with the dynamic part.

Comment: *"I **need** a class that represents a variable of a specific type"*  Do you? What are you really trying to achieve here? This feels very much like an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info)

Comment: I don't think I am XY-ing. I want to be able to write `var1 = Variable(int)` and `var2 = Variable(bool)`. Both `var1` and `var2` can be treated as their base types and as a `Variable`.

Comment: But *why*? Why not use the actual types? How is `var1 = Variable(int);var1.value = 7` better than `var1 = 7`? Alternatively, why can't you use composition (which can very easily be dynamic)?

Comment: And, what would `isinstance(Variable(int), Variable)` output?

Comment: Imagine a class with some attributes, e.g. `Box(length: int)` Sometimes I want to instantiate with a specific integer value, like `box1 = Box(5)`. Sometimes, I want to mark `length` as something that might be changed: `var1 = Variable(int), box2 = Box(var1)`. The trick is that some other part of the code will change its value, but it will not edit box directly like `box.length = 10` but instead edit the `Variable`: `var1.value = 10`, and the `box2` will have the updated value by reference.

Comment: _And, what would isinstance(Variable(int), Variable) output?_  -> True

Comment: But that would imply that `isinstance(Variable(str), Variable(int))` should also be `True` by transition. Please, consider a far simpler approach such as composition.

Comment: If the caller needs to know to do `var1.value = 10` rather than `var1 = 10`, how much of a problem is it that the caller has to do `isinstance(var1.value, int)` rather than `isinstance(var, int)`?

Comment: i expect that this question will attract many comments by virtue of its open and unclear nature...